# Why a simple T-SQL UDF function makes the code execution 3 times slower

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm rewriting some old stored procedure and I've come across an unexpected performance issue when using a function instead of inline code.

The function is very simple as follow:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDateDifferenceInDays] 
(       
@first_date SMALLDATETIME, 
@second_date SMALLDATETIME
)
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN 

RETURN ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, @first_date, @second_date))

END
```

So I've got two identical queries, but one uses the function and the other does the calculation in the query itself:

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, [mytable].first_date, [mytable].second_date))
```

Now the query with the inline code runs 3 times faster than the one using the function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have is a scalar UDF ( takes 0 to n parameters and returns a scalar value ). Such UDFs typically cause a row-by-row operation of your query, unless called with constant parameters, with exactly the kind of performance degradation that you're experiencing with your query.

See [here](http://www.sqlmag.com/Articles/Index.cfm?ArticleID=42139&DisplayTab=Article),  [here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/articleid/39036/39036.html) and [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2005/sql-server-udfs/) for detailed explanations of the peformance pitfalls of using UDFs.

Comment: Thank you for posting. Your last link is a good empirical analysis on this problem but does not explain why it is this behaviour.

Comment: @nagul -- your first link is bad. Looks like SQLMag changed their URL.  Any chance this is the article ? http://sqlmag.com/user-defined-function-udf/udfs-endanger-performance

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the usage context, the query optimizer may be able to analyze the inline code and figure out a great index-using query plan, while it doesn't "inline the function" for similarly detailed analysis and so ends up with an inferior query plan when the function is involved. Look at the two query plans, side by side, and you should be able to confirm (or disprove) this hypothesis pretty easily!

Comment: Thanks for posting. I analysed the two execution plans and they are identical except that the one that does not use scalar UDFs has "parallelism" before executin Nested Loops (3 occurences). I know parallelism improves the execution time as it takes advantage of multiple processors; but shall I assume it is all caused by the lack of parallelism in the execution plan?