# Minimum/Maximum function in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am not asking about the aggregate Min/Max functions here.  I would like to know if there are functions to get the mix or max of two values as in:

```
SELECT Maximum(a,b)
FROM Foo
```

If table Foo contains

```
a b
1 2
4 3
```

Then the results should be 2, then 4.

I can do this with an IF or CASE statement, but you'd think there would be some simple math functions for this.

Thank you,

Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not. You can write your own UDFs but UDFs can [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245962/why-a-simple-t-sql-udf-function-makes-the-code-execution-3-times-slower) queries down. Another option is to UNPIVOT the data so you can use the aggregate function. But for small applications CASE is best.